# Deploy images on Rancher from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rancher

I am trying to deploy my docker images from Docker Hub to Rancher. When I do that, I am getting only updating status and then after some time, I am getting deployment timeout. I am new to Rancher and trying to go through documents but not able to understand it properly. Can anyone assist me to do this?

I already tried to pull the image and after some time it shows "deployment does not have minimum availability".

**Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml file configuration:**

```
stages:
  - build
  - publish

.build: &build_template
  stage: build
  image: microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-alpine
  cache:
    key: "$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
    paths:
      - .nuget/
  script:
    - dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --packages ./.nuget/
    - dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o ./docker/publish/

develop_build:
  <<: *build_template
  only:
    - develop
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - docker/

.docker: &docker_template
  stage: publish
  image: docker:stable-dind
  script:
    - mkdir docker/app/
    - mv docker/publish/$ASSEMBLY_NAME.* docker/app/
    - mv docker/publish/*.config docker/app/
    - mv docker/publish/*.json docker/app/
    - cp Dockerfile docker/
    - docker build -t $TAG ./docker/
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG

develop_docker:
  <<: *docker_template
  only:
    - develop
  dependencies:
    - develop_build
  variables:
    ASSEMBLY_NAME: app
    TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

**Below is my DockerFile:**

```
# Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers set
COPY ./DataStore/DataStore/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY *[^.csproj] ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime images
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataStore.dll"]
```

**I want to run my C# web APIs after deploying it to Rancher.**

Comment: What version of rancher are you using?

Comment: @ScottAnderson version 2.0.8. I have no idea what is going on with Rancher. It is for my university.

Comment: Can you please check the logs of the pod? Also can you please check the events/status of the workload as well the as the pod? They should give you some idea as to why the deployment is not starting.

Comment: @leodotcloud what i did is i created one test image on docker hub and pulled it on rancher. Now i can see that image running on Rancher but when i try to run it from server with ip, swagger page is not opening..

Comment: `when i try to run it from server with ip, swagger page is not opening`
This statement is not clear to me. If you are trying to access the container, you need to use NodePort or Ingress to expose the workload outside of the kubernetes cluster.